# Curl error: Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)

Tags: php, curl

Долго искал решение проблемы, когда интересующий в плане парсинга сайт не желает без боя отдать свой html код. Перерыл поиск и все темы связанные с этим вопросом и уперся в одну ошибку, на которую нет конкретных решений: Curl error: Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?) Пример кода:

```
$ch = curl_init("https://instant-monitor.com/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/535.6 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/16.0.897.0 Safari/535.6');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, 'ftp://2allwebsite@s2000.ucoz.net/scripts/cacert.pem');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, '/cookie.txt');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 3);
$hyiplogs = curl_exec($ch);
if(curl_exec($ch) === false) {echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
} else {
echo 'Operation completed without any errors';
}
curl_close($ch);
var_dump($hyiplogs);
```

Здесь получаем ошибку:

Curl error: Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)
bool(false)

Если отменить проверку сертификата

```
$ch = curl_init("https://instant-monitor.com/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/535.6 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/16.0.897.0 Safari/535.6');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, '/cookie.txt');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 3);
$hyiplogs = curl_exec($ch);
if(curl_exec($ch) === false) {echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
} else {
echo 'Operation completed without any errors';
}
curl_close($ch);
var_dump($hyiplogs);
```

получаем ошибку: Curl error: gnutls_handshake() failed: A TLS fatal alert has been received.
bool(false)

Помогите победить проблему. Мой сайт находиться на хостинге Ucoz. Версия PHP - 5.2.12, версия Curl - 7.21.0. Доступ к php.ini отсутствует.

Comment: попробуйте подсунуть в curl файл с сертификатами отсюда https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html

Comment: Первый раз вижу что сертификат находится на удаленном сервере. Примеры и документацию, либо исходники CURL смотрели чтобы такое пихать для [CURLOPT_CAINFO](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_CAINFO.html)?

Comment: Да, пробовал по разному и (/cacert.pem), и (cacert.pem), результат один и тот же: Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)

Comment: Все файлы загружаются по FTP через Filezilla

Comment: кто-то может помочь по данному вопросу?